# Google Cloud Function; Use Google Cloud Rest APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The situation is that in my cloud function, I need to create VM instance from an instance template. I was using `@google-cloud/compute` package, but it doesn't provide a way to do so.

Now, I am trying to use the REST APIs, however I can't get it to authorize. I am using API keys, as instructed on this page [Use api keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys).

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<ID>/zones/us-central1-a/instances?key=<API_KEY>&sourceInstanceTemplate=projects/<TEMPLATE_URL>
```

There is a post body as well, but that's irrelevant since the error is with the authorization.

**I got `login required` error.**

I do have a service account that I use with the cloud storage nodejs client on the same cloud function, but I couldn't find documentation on how I could use the same service account with the REST APIs on a cloud function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation you linked](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys), the usage of API keys are restricted to a limited number of API's:

> A limited number of GCP services allow access using only an API key:
>
> - Google Cloud Natural Language API
> - Google Cloud Speech API
> - Google Cloud Translation API
> - Google Cloud Vision API
> - Google Cloud Endpoints
> - Google Cloud Billing Catalog API
> - Cloud Data Loss Prevention API

Hence it is not possible to use API keys to do REST calls to Compute Engine resources.

However, you have the option to use the [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#google-apis-nodejs-client).

I did a small example on my side, that creates the Compute Engine instance from an instance template, in a Cloud Function running in Node.js 8 (in Node.js 6 you don't have the option of creating async calls, I believe, and you benefit from this calls since you don't have to wait for the instance to be created, in order to get a response from the CF):

**index.js**

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const compute = google.compute('v1');

exports.helloWorld = async data => {
  const authClient = await google.auth.getClient({
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute',
    ],
  });
  const projectId = await google.auth.getProjectId();
  const result = await compute.instances.insert({
    auth: authClient,
    project: projectId,
    zone: "us-east1-c",
    sourceInstanceTemplate: "projects/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/global/instanceTemplates/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME-template",
    resource: {
        name: "example-vm-from-api-call",
    },
  });
  console.log('done');
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "google-auth-library": "3.0.0",
    "googleapis-common": "0.6.0",
    "googleapis": "36.0.0"
  }
}
```

I have hard-coded the instance name to be always `example-vm-from-api-call`, but when doing requests to the cloud function, you can pass a name for the instance in the parameters, and use it to create the instance.

As well, note that the authentication is made by executing the line `const authClient = await google.auth.getClient(...)`. This takes the application default authenticated account, which is the service account that executes the Cloud Function.

This service account has by default the permissions `project/editor`, which are enough to create CE VMs, however if you ever use another account to execute these functions, you will have to give it the correct access scopes (see the parameters of aforenamed function).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the post. The documentation says that the listed APIs only allow authentication with API keys, English isn't my native language so I may be misinterpreting, doesn't that mean that those APIs don't allow other modes of authentication such as, OAuth, service account?

And yes, I had already started looking into googleapis, although it's huge, but I don't see any other option as of now.

Comment: No, the listed APIs can also use Oauth or a service account, and additionally they are the only ones which also support using API Keys. I believe that the best option is to use the Client Libraries to do this API calls. It is also possible to do CURL calls directly to  `www.googleapis.com/...` adding the [request body](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert#body.request_body) manually, but it is possible that it doesn't work with some APIs, and I haven't tried.

Comment: Google APIs support 3 different authorization schemes: API key, user acct auth (OAuth2 client ID), and service account auth (JWT/OAuth2). Most of the time, it's one of the latter pair. GCP APIs are usually server-to-server, meaning service accounts, but as stated here, some not many (public data access) also still allow for the API keys. OTOH, those accessing USER data, i.e., Drive files, can be accessed w/user or svc acct auth (but never API key). API keys can be lost/compromised easily, so that's why most Google APIs have you using an OAuth scheme instead. Videos & blog posts at some point.